# MongoDB aggregation with multiple arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following two items inserted into the collection "frames":

```
frame1 = {
          "number": 1,

          "hobjects": [ { "htype": 1, "weight": 50 },
                        { "htype": 2, "weight": 220 },
                        { "htype": 2, "weight": 290 },
                        { "htype": 3, "weight": 450 } ],

          "sobjects": [ { "stype": 1, "size": 10.0 },
                        { "stype": 2, "size": 5.1 },
                        { "stype": 2, "size": 6.5 } ],
          }

frame2 = {
          "number": 2,

          "hobjects": [ { "htype": 1, "weight": 61 },
                        { "htype": 2, "weight": 210 },
                        { "htype": 2, "weight": 250 } ],

          "sobjects": [ { "stype": 1, "size": 12.1 },
                        { "stype": 2, "size": 4.9 },
                        { "stype": 2, "size": 6.2 },
                        { "stype": 2, "size": 5.7 } ],
          }

frames.insert(frame1)
frames.insert(frame2)
```

Now i want to do a query on the partial frame data:

```
query = { "hobjects.htype": 3, "sobjects.stype": 2 }
db.frames.find(query)
```

which results in:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('545b6ea7b9ad9a03462d743b'), u'hobjects': [{u'htype': 1, u'weight': 50}, {u'htype': 2, u'weight': 220}, {u'htype': 2, u'weight': 290}, {u'htype': 3, u'weight': 450}], u'number': 1, u'sobjects': [{u'stype': 1, u'size': 10.0}, {u'stype': 2, u'size': 5.1}, {u'stype': 2, u'size': 6.5}]}
```

and its not what i exactly would like to have. I want to have collection filtered according to the query so that i get the following result instead:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('545b6ea7b9ad9a03462d743b'), u'hobjects': [{u'htype': 3, u'weight': 450}], u'number': 1, u'sobjects': [{u'stype': 2, u'size': 5.1}, {u'stype': 2, u'size': 6.5}]}
```

The only solution I found involves aggregation with unwinding and grouping per collection:

```
query = { "hobjects.htype": 3, "sobjects.stype": 2 }
db.frames.aggregate([
    { "$match": query },
    { "$unwind": "$hobjects" },
    { "$match": dict((key, value) for key, value in query.iteritems() if "hobjects." in key) },
    { "$group": { "_id": "$_id", "number": { "$first": "$number" } , "hobjects": { "$push": "$hobjects" }, "sobjects": { "$first": "$sobjects" } } },
    { "$unwind": "$sobjects" },
    { "$match": dict((key, value) for key, value in query.iteritems() if "sobjects." in key) },
    { "$group": { "_id": "$_id", "number": { "$first": "$number" } , "hobjects": { "$first": "$hobjects" }, "sobjects": { "$push": "$sobjects" } } },
    ])
```

I guess thats not a very effective and flexible way of doing queries. I wonder if there are any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that your server is MongoDB 2.6 or greater then you can always do this:

```js
db.frames.aggregate([

    // Still helps to match the documents by conditions to filter
    { "$match": {
        "hobjects.htype": 3, "sobjects.stype": 2 
    }},

    // Now filter inline using $map and $setDifference
    { "$project": {
        "number": 1,
        "hobjects": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$hobjects",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": {
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$eq": [ "$$el.htype", 3 ] },
                            "$$el",
                            false
                        ]
                    }
                }},
                [false]
            ]
        },
        "sobjects": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$sobjects",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": {
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$eq": [ "$$el.stype", 2 ] },
                            "$$el",
                            false
                        ]
                    }
                }},
                [false]
            ]
        } 
    }}
])
```

The catch here is that basic projection and things like [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) can only presently match the **first** element in an array that matches the condition. So to do anything more you need some form of advanced manipulation that is only available to things such as the aggregation framework.

The [**`$setDiffence`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) and [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operators give you an "inline" way of processing arrays and in fact "sets" within an individual document. This works out to be a bit more efficient than using [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), particularly where large arrays are concerned.

JavaScript notation here I know (mostly in comments), but it's basically the same as python.

Comment: Thank you @NeilLunn! Looks like its an optimal alternative. Will try it out!

Comment: Tested the solution and it worked for my example case. Although I would prefer more generic solution with arbitrary query on the entire object data.

Comment: @Neil Lunn - Can you please help to write this query in java driver. Thanks

Comment: @PVH If you have your own question then please [Ask A Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). StackOverflow is not a threaded discussion or mailing list. You ask questions and people provide answers.

Answer (score 0):

Following aggregation may help you

```
db.frames.aggregate({"$unwind":"$hobjects"},{"$unwind":"$sobjects"},{"$match":{"hobjects.htype": 3, "sobjects.stype": 2}},{"$group":{"_id":"$_id","u'hobjects":{"$first":"$hobjects"},"u'number":{"$first":"$number"},"u'sobjects":{"$push":"$sobjects"}}})
```

Comment: Cartesian problem with unwinding multiple arrays. Means you just duplicated elements of one of them

Comment: @NeilLunn thank's for suggestion I will work on solving that problem

Comment: Go ahead. That problem has been solved many times before, I'm sure I've answered it many times myself. But that is not what the OP asked. Their code is fine, they just asked for something more optimal, and a possible explanation as to why what they are doing is necessary.